# -> Unable to parse page for ticker: None for finviz api

Tags: python, parsing, stock

I am trying to get stocks from Finviz api from Marioriostoev but I am getting a parse error. It seems as it is not getting the right field. This program used to work perfect. However now it is not. I don´t know in which module it os ocuurring, The program is supposed to take the filter get the stkcs that match the filter, put them in an Excel file and the put their charts images intoa folder

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
!pip install finviz~=1.4.6
from finviz.screener import Screener

from finviz.screener import Screener

import os
import datetime
Current_Date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime ('%d-%b-%Y')

# Input
valperiod = input('Enter Type of Graphic d,w,m: ')

if valperiod == "w" or "m":
     valta ="0"
else:
     valta = "1"

# Create the Folder where the data ancharts are going to be stores
newpath = 'D:\\Users\\Jose Mizrahi\\Documents\\finviz-master\\finviz-master\\'+'Breakout1 '+str(Current_Date)+'\\'
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)

# Get dict of available filters
# filters dict contains the corresponding filter tags
filters = Screener.load_filter_dict()

filters = [
    "cap_small",
    "fa_sales5years_pos",
    "sh_curvol_o200",
    "sh_relvol_o1",
    "ta_highlow52w_b0to10h",
    "ty=c&p=w&tas=0",
    "ta_volatility_mo3&ft=4&o=ticker"
]
stock_list = Screener(filters=filters, table="Performance")

print(stock_list)



# Monthly, Candles, Large, No Technical Analysis
if valperiod == "d":
    stock_list.get_charts(period="d", chart_type='c', size='l', ta="1")
else:
    stock_list.get_charts(period=valperiod, chart_type='c', size='l', ta="0")   

# period='d' > daily
# period='w' > weekly
# period='m' > monthly

# chart_type='c' > candle
# chart_type='l' > lines

# size='m' > small
# size='l' > large

# ta='1' > display technical analysis
# ta='0' > ignore technical analysis


print("Retrieving stock data...")
stock_data = stock_list.get_ticker_details()
print(stock_data)

os.chdir(newpath)

# Export the screener results to CSV file
stock_list.to_csv("JosyBreakout1.csv")

# Create a SQLite database
# stock_list.to_sqlite("sp500.sqlite")
```

Comment: Hello, please post more details about the parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

The list of stocks doesn't by chance include NONE or NULL does it? I did find a few APIs utterly blew a gasket if you tried to look up stocks with those names. I had I think NONE show up in one of my tables once. Looking up NONE or NULL now with IB API it gives a "No security definition found for the request" but in the past as soon as the program requested that data, not only did the API connection from the program to Interactive Brokers Trading Workstation close, the connection from TWS to the server closed too, stocks dropped off the display and everything.  (TWS then auto-reconnected and it came back up.)  .

If you have it print "Retrieving stock data..." then error out, it has a problem on the line that does get_ticker_details.  If it errors out before that than I suppose it's a problem getting the data to draw the charts.

I'll note the NoneType in Python is "None" when it's converted to a string.  If the line that returns stock_list got no stocks as a result, maybe whatever variable stores what stocks to graph ended up being a NoneType rather than an empty list?  Then it'd crash when you go to graph.  I would look at your filters first to see if they're too strict, or if you ran it on a holiday or weekend maybe there was just an empty result and it'll run fine otherwise.

I'm not a user of finviz myself, but of course there's always that possibility that something in the API changed and you'll have to change those filters around slightly (or just use a newer version on that "pip install finviz" line.)